# Processes sharing queue not terminating properly

Tags: python

I have a multiprocessing application where the parent process creates a queue and passes it to worker processes. All processes use this queue for creating a queuehandler for the purpose of logging. There is a worker process reading from this queue and doing logging.

The worker processes continuously check if parent is alive or not. The problem is that when I kill the parent process from command line, all workers are killed except for one. The logger process also terminates. I don't know why one process keeps executing. Is it because of any locks etc in queue? How to properly exit in this scenario?  I am using

```
    sys.exit(0)
```

for exiting.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sys.exit(0)` only if there is no other chance. It's always better to cleanly finish each thread / process. You will have some `while` loop in your Process. So just do `break` there, so that it can come to an end.

Tidy up before you leave, i.e., release all handles of external resources, e.g., files, sockets, pipes.

Somewhere in these handles might be the reason for the behavior you see.